# Azure B2C samples - SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail - skip email collection step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working with the SignUpOrSignInWithPhoneOrEmail.xml file from the B2C samples and I was wondering if anyone else has been able to figure out how to modify the custom template to skip the email collection step entirely when a user registers via a phone number. The country I am developing for has a low rate of email usage - and phone numbers are the only identifying information we can rely on.

The first thing I tried was to simply remove the email collection step from the user journey as defined here:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>isLocalAccountSignIn</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>isEmailSignUp</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithPhone_CollectEmailAddress" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber_CollectEmailAddress" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

But that just caused an error to be thrown - probably because one of the further `TechnicalProfile` or `UserJourney` definitions rely on it in a way that I am yet to decipher.

After that I tried just marking the claim as not-required as below

```xml
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="false" />
```

which gave me the behavior I expected (the field could be filled without being verified) - but this just seems worse and I would like to remove the step entirely.

I am extremely new to custom policies and feel like the answer I am looking for is probably obvious - any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My requirement is that the user can login/register with either their email/phone exclusively (and link the email address to the phone number). I have since found a sample that allows for this behavior [here](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-samples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a week of learning and a lot of trial and error - but I was able to cobble together something that meets my requirement. I'm not an expert - so I can't guarantee that it's perfect but I've uploaded a sample to Github, that you can view [here](https://github.com/jacojvv-dev/Azure-B2C-Sign-Up-With-Phone-Sign-In-With-Phone-Or-Email) if you are interested.

For those that are wondering why simply removing step 3 does not work it's because step uses the technical profile with the id of `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber_CollectEmailAddress` and this technical profile calls `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonPhoneNumber` as a validation profile. `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonPhoneNumber` is responsible for writing the user data to Azure AD. Steps 4+ rely on the fact that the user is already in AD and thus - they fail.

If you are new to B2C Custom Policies - I highly recommend [this series](https://www.wintellect.com/hello-world-and-then-some-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-policies-part-1-introduction/) of blog posts to get you up and running quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to highlight a keyword here: SignUpOrSignInWithPhone**Or**Email. Yeah, says Or, not AND. Ugh. So lame. Your phone-only scenario is totally valid, for reasons like you described, yet it's not in-the-box simple to do with b2c.

I found this post that may be helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/115660/azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-with-phone.html

Basically, you need to use the **SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa** template.

Also found this that may be useful:
https://blog.hametbenoit.info/2019/12/19/azure-ad-b2c-new-phone-sign-in-authentication-method-available-preview

Meanwhile... it would be a VERY good idea for Microsoft to make development of Custom Policies actually possible for mere mortals, without requiring us to dissect huge XML files and spend hours and hours trying to connect the dots between each line therein, and the effects in the UI in the end.

Comment: Thanks - I agree. It's extremely difficult for me to reason about the changes I am making and the learning curve is steep.

I have since found a sample that fits my requirements - but now I need to figure out how to do my own reset password and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the profile of the user from AD using EITHER email or phone (there is an AZ sample for retrieving by email only), so I'll keep struggling for the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample here to do a purely sign in with phone journey.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number

Here you can learn how the schema works
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki

Comment: Thanks - I have since found a sample that allows for the behavior I require as mentioned in the edit above. I don't know if there is a MS based example of what I found above that might be more up to date?